# RapidAPI: undefined method `get_company' for "FB":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, unirest, rapidapi

I am trying to pull data from IEX Trading API via RapidAPI in my Rails app. I have created a search form where the query will be used to obtain the data, however the following error message appears even though it works fine in the console (with the query being "FB" in this example):

**undefined method 'get_company' for "FB":String**

stock.rb

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  validates :ticker, uniqueness: true

  def self.get_company
    response = Unirest.get "https://investors-exchange-iex-trading.p.rapidapi.com/stock/#{@stock}/company",
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key" => [xxx]
    }
    company = response.body
    @stock = Stock.create(
      ticker: company["symbol"],
      name: company["companyName"],
      exchange: company["Exchange"],
      sector: company["industry"],
      website: company["website"],
      description: company["description"]
    )
  end
end
```

stocks_controller.rb

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search
  end

  def result
    @stock = params[:stock]
    @stock.get_company unless @stock.nil?
  end
end
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
def result
     @stock = params[:stock]
     Stock.get_company(@stock) unless @stock.nil? end

def self.get_company(stock)
@stock = stock
 response = Unirest.get "https://investors-exchange-iex-trading.p.rapidapi.com/stock/#{@stock}/company", headers: { "X-RapidAPI-Key" => [xxx] }
```